# How to autocomplete from dropdown menu in Arcade?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I have an ArcGIS Online App where a user is expected to enter an input into one of the fields. This field has a dropdown/domain list with more than 2000 predefined values.

I would like to implement an Arcade script that will reduce the number of choices from the dropdown, based on the matching letters typed in the field. Something like [this example](https://resource.esriuk.com/blog/sweet-treats-create-tailored-workflows-using-arcade/) under the Attribute rules section would probably do the job.

Any idea how the script to achieve this would look like?